# remove specific characters from NSString

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa, nsstring

I wants to remove specific characters or group substring from NSString.

mean

NSString *str = @" **hello I am #39;doing Parsing  So $#39;I get many symbols in &my response**";

I wants remove #39;      and     $#39; and &   (Mostly these three strings comes in response)

**output should be :** hello I am doing Parsing So i get many symbols in my response

Side Question : I can't write & #39; without space here, because it converted in ' <-- this symbol. so i use $ in place of & in my question.

Answer (score 14):

you should use `[str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"#39" withString:@""]`
or you need replace strings of concrete format like "#number"?

Answer (score 13):

try below code ,i think you got whatever you want simply change the charecterset,

```
NSString *string = @"hello I am #39;doing Parsing So $#39;I get many symbols in &my response";
NSCharacterSet *trim = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"#39;$&"];
NSString *result = [[string componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:trim] componentsJoinedByString:@""];
NSLog(@"%@", result);
```

Comment: This is good if you are removing single characters.  All #, 3, 9, $, & will get removed which is probably not what he wants.  (Still a good trick though.)